# Как случайно распределить некоторое количество прямоугольников так, чтобы они не пересекались, а также, отсеять те, которые не уместились?

Tags: алгоритм, прямоугольники

У меня произвольное количество произвольных прямоугольников, а также прямоугольник, в котором их надо случайно распределить. Не обязательно, чтобы они стояли вплотную. Но обязательно, чтобы они не пересекались. С теми прямоугольниками, которые не влезают из-за того, что они больше исходного или для них не осталось места, ничего делать не надо: они просто отсеиваются.

Comment: Ну так в чем вопрос, пройти по всем прямоугольникам, в них пройти по всем углам и определить пересечение этой точки и другого прямоугольника. Для этого у каждого прямоугольника должна быть функция проверки принадлежит ли ему данная координата.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Обычная ошибка в нахождении пересечения прямоугольников. Оно находится не так. Типичный пример - пересечение в виде креста.

Comment: Прямоугольники пересекаются, если расстояние между центрами меньше (или равно) полусумме размеров, - по обеим координатам.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, вы предлагаете накидать все прямоугольники, а потом убирать один из двух пересекающихся, если такие есть?

Comment: @Igor Тоже интересный вариант.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Это *правильный* вариант :).

Comment: @user397059 Да в моем варианте убирать те, которые не пересекаются с другими. а алгоритм пересечения выберите любой. У Игоря тоже рабочий вариант.

Comment: @Igor не оспариваю

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю, этот вариант мне подойдёт. Только я ещё планирую подсчитать, сколько раз пересекается каждый прямоугольник с другими, и удалять тот, у которого это число максимально. В цикле.